# Targeting an iframe in another iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I have a link on the first page (we'll call that index.php).  I am using javascript to attempt to reload an iframe that is in another iframe.

I tried...

```
$("#link1").click(function() {
  document.getElementById('iframe2').src = 'thepage.php';
});
```

But this is simply looking for the that iframe in the page where the link is.  I am trying to create this so that it looks for the second iframe that is inside the parent page's iframe.  How do I do this?  Is it even possible?

Comment: It's NOT a duplicate.  The other question your are referring to is referring to two iframes in the same page.  This one is about an iframe within and iframe (two separate pages).

Comment: user2284703 is correct.  This should not have been marked as duplicate.

Comment: It would improve this question to include a sample of the HTML that shows the problem.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Did that on a previous question that I ended up deleting because the coding was far too complicated for anyone to come up with an answer.  But nevermind... finally figured it out just now.  But I wont bother posting my solution here since "some" people refer to this as a duplicate question.

Comment: @user2284703 - You should still post your solution.  This would still be considered productive.  Don't let people who can't read deter you from doing it

Answer (score 1):

You can access the parent document from within the iframe using window.parent and the top most parent using window.top.

Once you've got access to the parent, you can access the other iframe from there.

Example:

```
$('#link1').click(function(){
     $('#iframe2', window.parent.document).attr('src','thepage2.php');
});
```

This should search for the iframe2 element in the parent document of the document which contains the link1 element and change it's src attribute.

**NOTE:**  this will only work if all the iframes are pointing to the same domain (all under your control).  Otherwise you are violating cross site scripting policies.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you're trying to do, `iframes` just simply don't work that way. They embed documents into your document; they don't make them part of your document.

You have to put your script on the page that is in the first `iframe`. If you don't have access to that document, then there's nothing you can do.

Comment: If this was the case, the OP would not have said he solved it... same goes for @HaukurHaf as he has also posted a solution.

Comment: It is the case, what the OP was asking to do violates cross site scripting policies, he never said he was successful at doing it, he said he found a solution, probably one like @HaukurHaf gave, which involves doing exactly what I said, having access to the document in the iframe.

Comment: Andyet still people simply assume they understand things that were not insinuated upon.  For example... none of the pages in or outside of the frames are outside of my own domain.  I never said they were.  So how would i not have access to a specific document?  This is crazy especially considering that I figured it out and yet people here say it cant be done.

Comment: Iframes are typically used to load elements from cross domain, which is basically all they're good for these days. Frames are a dated practice, if all of your pages are on the same domain then why don't you use something like jquery to .load() or .clone() the page elements you need from other pages? Also, if you've found a solution, then why aren't you sharing it?